# Convolutional layers with 3 channels image

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I would like to use the DQN code from the Keras-rl library (https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl/blob/master/examples/dqn_atari.py) with 3 channels images (without grayscale conversion).

How to change the code to do it ? I tried to remove this line : `img = img.resize(INPUT_SHAPE).convert('L') # resize and convert to grayscale` but I have dimension errors..

I added `from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')` 
and I change the network achitecture :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Permute((3, 1, 2),input_shape=(200,200,3)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda a: a / 255.0))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1), activation=activation))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(128))
for i in xrange(nb_layers):
    model.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation=activation))
model.add(Dense(env.action_space.n + 1))
model.add(Lambda(lambda a: K.expand_dims(a[:, 0], axis=-1) + a[:, 1:], output_shape=(env.action_space.n,)))
print(model.summary())
```

but at runtime :

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected permute_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 200, 200, 3)

How to handle the 3 channel images ?

Comment: What is the shape of the array of images which you use to train your model?

Comment: the shape of the image is (84,84,3)

Comment: that's not possible, as your input_Shape is (200,200,3). The input of your array of images should therefore be (x, 200, 200, 3). x stands for the number of images.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, the image shape is (200,200,3). I don't know why the input is (1, 1, 200, 200, 3) , it should be (x , 200, 200, 3). Maybe it's a problem with the library

Comment: Can you add code about how you load the images in python and how you prepare them for your model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in the posted code, but my guess is that when you removed the resize line you accidentally added a `,` at the end of the prior line which initializes the image array. Python will parse `img = abc(),` as `img = (abc(),)`. That error matches your 5-dimensional shape.